# Why is the estimation of system constraints needed in system design interviews?

Tags: architecture, system-design

I'm a junior software developer with no experience in system design and currently I'm preparing for a system design interview. I have read in many websites that I have to come up with some estimates of the scale of the system I'm going to design. In order to help me when I'm focusing on scaling, partitioning, load balancing and caching.

Examples of these estimates:

- Number of total active users
- Total number of requests per second
- Total size of data saved per second and per year

My problem is that, I don't know what to do with these estimates?

In the interview, I can suggest adding a load balance and more hosts, add caching layer, add master slave database servers, ... and more, to increase the performance and I can discuss the trade-offs of each solution and which solution to choose in the future. But why should I to come with these numbers?

For example how will the number of requests per second affect my design?
Do hosts have a maximum number of requests per second? Do database management systems have a maximum size? I think that the answer is no to both questions and it depends on many factors and to determine the number of hosts or the need of database sharding or master and slave servers design  in real life depends on practical experiments and testing. Please, correct me if I'm mistaken, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*For example how will the number of requests per second affect my design?*
10 requests per second, no need for a load balancer, 10,000 requests per second, you need to look at load balancers, stateless scaling, etc

*Do hosts have a maximum number of requests per second?* Yes, it's not absolute, but at some point you will need to architecturally design in more scalability.

*Do database management systems have a maximum size?* Practically, yes.  It also makes you consider things like NoSQL options etc.  If you are looking at petabyte-scale data, you should probably think twice about throwing it all in a relational database.

In real life, they aren't always cut-and-dry, but it can start the conversation, and focus it on the most important scaling factors.